# I have run into an issue with my text game loot system

Tags: java, text

```
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {
            JList l = (JList)m.getSource();
            // If click twice then collect item
            if (m.getClickCount() == 2 && l.getSelectedValue() != null) {
                String i = l.getSelectedValue().toString();
                int q = Integer.parseInt(i.replaceAll("\\)","").split("\\(")[1]), q1 = 0;
                String i2 = i.split("\\(")[0];
                String i3 = i2.substring(0, i2.length() - 1);
                if (q > 1) {
                    q1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many would you like to take?"));
                }
                else
                    q1 = 1;
                PlayerHandler.addItem(i3, q1);
                if (q1 == q) {
                    lmb.remove(l.getSelectedIndex());
                }
                else {
                    String t = l.getSelectedValue().toString();
                    int s = l.getSelectedIndex();
                    lmb.remove(s);
                    lmb.add(s, t.replaceAll(Integer.toString(q), Integer.toString(q - q1)));
                }
                lma.clear();
                PlayerHandler.listInventory(lma);
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to do a learn as I go text game project and I've run into an issue with collecting items after an enemy is dead.

When the inventory comes up and there are two or more of each item a window will pop up asking the player to type in how many they wish to take, lets say there are 5 wooden swords in the inventory, it will allow them to take 100 wooden swords, placing them in the inventory and leaving a "Wooden Sword (-95)" in the monster loot table.

If you need more information let me know, it's pretty late and my thinker is pretty fried.

Comment: Soo...do a comparison between what the user has requested and what you have, when they don't match, re-prompt the user.  You might consider using a [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) which can condfigured with a max/min value

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
q1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many would you like to take?"));
```

To:

```
q1 = Math.min(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many would you like to take?")), q);
```

Comment: You should add an explanation.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I should have explained my reasoning.  

In the description, it is mentioned that "If there are two or more of each item, then the dialog pops up."

    In the posted code, you see the line:  
    `if (q > 1) {
        q1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many would you like to take?"));
    }`

Based on the description, the 'q' variable would be the number of items available in the inventory.  Therefore, using Math.min with q would mean "You can take at most 'q' items"

Answer (score 0):

Validate their input. You can make a simple comparison to make sure that the amount they requested is less than or equal to the amount available. Additionally, based on your code snippet I suggest you use more descriptive variable names than m, 1, q, q1, i, i2, and i3. When you come back to try and work on that code later, it will be easier to remember what everything does if your variables are properly named.